# Disable global Spock Mock class for one test

Tags: java, testing, spock

Hello I have a global Mock in the setup method but would like to disable it for one test in the same class. Is it possible?

```
class Test extends Specification {

  void setup() {
    GroovyMock(Utils, global: true)
    Utils.getRemoteBranches(*_) >> new ArrayList<String>()
  }

  void "test1"() {
    given:
    Object context = getContext()

    when:
    ...
```

Comment: It's not possible. I don't think the spec would be readable if you did this. Looks like you want to achieve the DRY principle but forgot about tests' readability

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename your `setup` method, and call it in your `given` step.
There is also a `setup` keyword in Spock. It has the same meaning as `given`.

For example, like this:

```
class Test extends Specification {

  void setupMock() {
    GroovyMock(Utils, global: true)
    Utils.getRemoteBranches(*_) >> new ArrayList<String>()
  }

  void "testWithMock"() {
    given:
    setupMock()
    Object context = getContext()

    when:
    // ...

  void "testWithoutMock"() {
    given:
    Object context = getContext()

    when:
    // ...

  }
```

In a way I agree to the comment regarding test readbility, if the tests without Mock are relatively important you should consider creating a separate `Specification`.